# Square a matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, biopython, skbio

Hello let say I have a df such as :

```
G1  G2  VALUE 
SP1 SP2 1
SP1 SP3 2
SP1 SP4 3
SP2 SP3 4
SP2 SP4 5
SP3 SP4 6
```

how can I get a the data as square ? (i.e., have the same number of rows and columns)

with something like

```
data = [[0,  1,  2,  3],
[1,  0, 4, 5],
[9, 10,  0,  8,  7],
[2, 4,  0,  6],
[3,  5,  6,  0]]

ids = ['SP1','SP2','SP3','SP4]

dm = DistanceMatrix(data, ids) (function from skbio package)
```

and get a matrix :

```
    SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4
SP1 0   1   2   3
SP2 1   0   4   5
SP3 2   4   0   6
SP4 3   5   6   0
```

And if some of you are familiar with it, how can we also do the same thing but with a 1/2 matrix :

```
SP1 0 
SP2 1   0   
SP3 2   4   0   
SP4 3   5   6   0
    SP1 SP2 SP3 SP4
```

(here is mor for biopython)
thanks a lot for your help

---

Other exemple

```
d = {'G1': ['SP1','SP2','SP2'], 'G2': ['SP3','SP3','SP1'],'VALUE' :[1,2,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I should get :

```
SP1 0
SP2 3   0
SP3 1   2  0
   SP1 SP2 SP3
```

and

```
SP1 0   3  1
SP2 3   0  2
SP3 1   2  0
   SP1 SP2 SP3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: In your second example SP2, SP1 has value 3 ... so could you explain why the second output does not have the value 3 but 1?

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, more or less:

```
In [257]: df
Out[257]: 
    G1   G2  VALUE
0  SP1  SP2      1
1  SP1  SP3      2
2  SP1  SP4      3
3  SP2  SP3      4
4  SP2  SP4      5
5  SP3  SP4      6

In [258]: df.pivot(index='G1', columns='G2', values='VALUE')
Out[258]: 
G2   SP2  SP3  SP4
G1                
SP1  1.0  2.0  3.0
SP2  NaN  4.0  5.0
SP3  NaN  NaN  6.0

In [259]: df.pivot(index='G1', columns='G2', values='VALUE').fillna(value=0)
Out[259]: 
G2   SP2  SP3  SP4
G1                
SP1  1.0  2.0  3.0
SP2  0.0  4.0  5.0
SP3  0.0  0.0  6.0
```

In response to the edit to the question:

```
In [277]: d = {'G1': ['SP1','SP2','SP2'], 'G2': ['SP3','SP3','SP1'],'VALUE' :[1,2,3]}

In [278]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

In [279]: d = df.pivot(index='G1', columns='G2', values='VALUE').fillna(value=0).to_dict()

In [280]: for s,dd in {**d}.items(): 
     ...:     for t,v in {**dd}.items(): 
     ...:         d.setdefault(t, {})[s] = v 
     ...:

In [281]: d
Out[281]: 
{'SP1': {'SP1': 0.0, 'SP2': 3.0, 'SP3': 1.0},
 'SP3': {'SP1': 1.0, 'SP2': 2.0},
 'SP2': {'SP1': 3.0, 'SP3': 2.0}}

In [282]: pd.DataFrame(data=d)
Out[282]: 
     SP1  SP3  SP2
SP1  0.0  1.0  3.0
SP2  3.0  2.0  NaN
SP3  1.0  NaN  2.0

In [283]: pd.DataFrame(data=d).fillna(value=0)
Out[283]: 
     SP1  SP3  SP2
SP1  0.0  1.0  3.0
SP2  3.0  2.0  0.0
SP3  1.0  0.0  2.0
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I edited with another smaller exemple where your code does not give the expected output, can you check where is the probleme please ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy.unique](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
import numpy as np

# find unique values from both columns (flattened)
idx = np.unique(df[['G1', 'G2']])

# cross tabulation of G1 and G2
res = pd.crosstab(index=df['G1'], columns=df['G2'], values=df['VALUE'], aggfunc='sum')

# reindex using unique values from both columns
res = res.reindex(index=idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0).fillna(0)

print(res)
```

**Output**

```
G2   SP1  SP2  SP3  SP4
G1                     
SP1  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0
SP2  0.0  0.0  4.0  5.0
SP3  0.0  0.0  0.0  6.0
SP4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

The first step:

```
# find unique values from both columns (flattened)
idx = np.unique(df[['G1', 'G2']])
```

creates:

```
['SP1' 'SP2' 'SP3' 'SP4']
```

the second step:

```
# cross tabulation of G1 and G2
res = pd.crosstab(index=df['G1'], columns=df['G2'], values=df['VALUE'], aggfunc='sum')
```

produces:

```
G2   SP2  SP3  SP4
G1                
SP1  1.0  2.0  3.0
SP2  NaN  4.0  5.0
SP3  NaN  NaN  6.0
```

then with the values obtained in step 1 reindex the DataFrame from step 2:

```
# reindex using unique values from both columns
res = res.reindex(index=idx, columns=idx, fill_value=0).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, I edited with another smaller exemple where your code does not give the expected output, can you check where is the probleme please ?